# Getting count of distinct groupings in RavenDB index

Tags: mapreduce, ravendb

I have a number of documents within RavenDB of the form:

```
{
    "Id": "composite of namespace and video id",
    "Namespace": "youtube",
    "VideoId": "12345678901",
    "Start": "00:00:05"
}
```

I have a number of documents that reference different segments of the actual thing; in this case, I have multiple documents representing different timestamps within a video.

What I'd like to do is get a count of the distinct number of `VideoId` instances for a particular `Namespace`.

At first, I thought I could handle the distinct in the mapping:

```
from v in docs.Clips.Select(c => new { c.Namespace, c.VideoId }).Distinct()
```

But that doesn't work, as that query isn't run over the *entire* document set (so it's impossible to perform a `Distinct` call here).

I've thought about trying to handle this in the reduce part, but I can't think of an aggregate operation which would group this appropriately.

The shape of the map/reduce structure right now is:

```
new { Type = "providercount", Key = "youtube", Count = 1 }
```

As this is part of a multi-map which produces a summary.

How can I produce the count of distinct `Namespace`/`VideoId` values with this document structure?

Comment: How to do a distinct count is a good question.  But if your `Id` values are something like `clips/youtube/12345678901` - then wouldn't there already be no possibility of duplicates?

Comment: @MattJohnson No, because the time component is embedded in the ID as well.  So the ID is something like: `clips/youtube=12345678901;t=10`.  Another valid ID might be `clips/youtube=12345678901;t=20`  So uniqueness among `VideoId` is *not* guaranteed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it might be to group by `NameSpace` and `VideoId`.  That will get you distinct items.  Then you would have to count all of those groups in a `TransformResults` section.  However, I don't recommend doing this with a large number of items.  Transformation steps run as part of the query, so performance would be a big problem.

A better approach would be to keep an additional separate document per video (not per clip).  For example:

```json
videos/youtube/12345678901
{
    "Title": "whatever",
    "NumberOfClips": 3,
    "Clips": ["clipid1","clipid2","clipid3"]
}
```

I put a few properties in there that might be useful for other purposes, but the main point is that there is only one document per video.

Building these documents could be done in a couple of different ways:

- You could write code in your application to add/update the `Video` documents at the same time you are writing `Clip` documents.
- You could write a map/reduce index for the `Clip` documents and group by the NameSpace/VideoId, and then use the [Indexed Properties Bundle](http://ravendb.net/docs/2.0/server/extending/bundles/indexed-properties) to maintain the `Video` documents from the results.

Either way, once you have the set of `Video` documents, you can then do a simple map/reduce on those to get the count of distinct videos.

Comment: I thought of the separate document per video, but that spits in the eye of document design, no?  Is there any way I can query an index in another index?  If I could do that, this would be rather simple.

Comment: Raven has "multi-map", but it doesn't have "multi-reduce".  The only way to get that is to use a document as an intermediary.  Indexed properties work well for that.   No, it doesn't upset document design principals.  One might say that you don't need a `clip` document at all - but even if you decide you do, then you can certainly duplicate data when necessary.

Comment: Why would I use the Indexed Properties bundle (also, I am on Raven HQ, so there's no guarantee that I can use it)?  I ask because the `Namespace` and `VideoId` properties are guaranteed to be immutable; they make up the `Id` of the document, so I don't know what I gain from using the indexed properties bundle (it looks like I'll be maintaining a separate documents).

Comment: On a side note, I can see the benefits of having a `Video` be the document and then the `Clip` being children of the document; the thing is, I need a distinct key to identify the clip (which makes me realize I'm going to have to re-key my `Clip` instances as I'll be displaying them on the web and will want to use an auto-generated ID and not the composite one I'm creating).

Comment: Indexed Properties bundle would maintain your `Video` documents for you - if all you need them for is the staging between two separate m/r indexes.  It sound like you are right and you don't need it.  You will probably have better luck with your app writing `Video` docs directly.

Comment: You could go either way with either embedding `Clip` data inside `Video` documents, or keeping them in their own documents.  You could go with an autogenerated id - sure.  You could still use a composite one if you wanted.  Either would be ok.